# I keep getting a double spend error

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon

I have no idea how barely any of this works i'm just trying to send my xmr and it keeps saying was rejected by daemon with status . Reason: double spend

Comment: Do you have enough to cover the gas fee?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you already spent your Moneros but your wallet couldn't save the wallet before closing the wallet software, now it thinks you didn't spend it.

You have to rescan your spent outputs using a trusted node.